# When should I choose to run an application as a daemon?

Tags: ubuntu-11.04, daemon

From the MongoDB manual:

To start the server as a daemon listening on port 5586 and sending all output to mongodb.log, we can do:

```
mongod --port 5586 --fork --logpath mongodb.log
```

What is the benefit to run an application as a daemon and when I should do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run MongoDB not forked (also known as a daemon), the instant you close your shell or SSH window, MongoDB will also be shutdown.

The reason why you want to fork it into the background (as a daemon) is so that you are able to continuously run MongoDB separate from your shell, that way it will run without interruption (unless you kill it yourself, or shutdown your computer).

Comment: Is it same as if I run `mongod --port 5586 --logpath mongodb.log &`? In other word, I use `&` to force the application run into the background?

Comment: Not entirely, if you use &, it will only be useful to your "session". If it is remote, and you kill your Terminal window, it will also kill Mongo as you are not logged in anymore to keep your background processes in place. If you are using a desktop interface, logging out will also kill this process.

Answer (score 1):

When you run an application as a daemon, it stays running after you log off of the computer.

This is useful for hosting services from your computer.